# Number of deaths during flood events

Tags: data-request

I am studying about flood events and its results. Because of that I need to find the number of people who die as a result of the flooding in the country scale. Is there any source that shows these statistics and numbers?

Comment: Do you want data for any specific country or the whole world?

Comment: Especially UK, but if there are global website, it would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emergency Events Database (EM-DAT) created by the Centre for Research on the Epidemiology of Disasters (CRED) has global disaster related data. It has free access to data of all kinds of disasters geophysical, hydrological, biological etc. in detail (including number of deaths). I think it would be helpful for you.

Visit the [EM-DAT website](https://www.emdat.be/) for details. To access the database [Click here](https://public.emdat.be/)